# How to determine the time for a radio signal to reach an observer? (relativity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Carrie is in a spaceship that is travelling towards a star in a straight-line at constant velocity as observed by Peter. Peter is at rest relative to the star.
[image]

Carrie travels at a speed of $0.4c$ relative to Peter.

Question:

According to Peter, as Carrie passes the star she sends a radio signal. Determine the time, as measured by Carrie, for the message to reach Peter?

Distance between the star and peter is $4.4$light-year

My initial working was that it must have something to do with "radio" but failed to make any progress. I also cannot make any use of $0.4c$. What is the general approach to this kind of question like an observer send a signal to another observer that is in a different frame?

Comment: Do you know the distance from Peter to the star?

Comment: Did you mean, “...as Carrie passes the star”?

Comment: @probably_someone Sorry It is a long question and I tried to condense to a smaller question. I included it

Comment: Posting what the phrase "Lorentz transformation" means to you would go towards the "show what work you've done" thing that people like to see for these sorts of questions.

Comment: @Acccumulation Look, I just need something to get me started, I already got the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since the star is $4.4$ light years away from Peter (and assuming this distance is measured in Peter's frame of reference) then any radio signal sent from where the star is will take $4.4$ years (as measured by Peter) to reach Peter because the signal travels at the speed of light. This is always true no matter how fast Carrie is going when she sends the signal.

As measured by Carrie the signal will take less than $4.4$ years to reach Peter. According to Carrie this is because the distance from the star to Peter is actually less than $4.4$ light years in her frame of reference. According to Peter it is because Carrie's clocks are running slow. The ratio between the time measured by Peter and the time measured by Carrie is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) for Carrie's speed of $0.4$c.